# Compared mySQL Values are Wrong

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to compare a mySQL database value to see if it's a 1 or 0. I can connect to the database and echo the entire table and column "Run" just fine with:

```
if($is_query_run = mysql_query($query)){
    echo "Successfully running query on database <br>";
    while($query_execute = mysql_fetch_assoc($is_query_run)){
        echo $query_execute['Run'];
    }
}
```

The mySQL table value for column "Run" and row ID "8" is: 1

But the code below outputs:

> Result: Resource id #5
>
> Database value is NOT 1 or 0 and thus something broke

```
$number = 8;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Run FROM users WHERE id='$number'");

echo 'Result: '.$result.'<br><br>';

if($result < 1) {
    echo "Database value is 0 and thus NOT updated today";
} elseif($result == 1) {
    echo "Database value is 1 and thus HAS been updated today";
} else {
    echo "Database value is NOT 1 or 0 and thus something broke";
}
```

And I'm just oh so confused.

Comment: The MySQL extensions that you are using was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was also removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL extensions that you are using was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was also removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

You cannot just echo $result. You will have to retrieve a row or loop over your resultset to be able to echo. That is why you are getting a Resource.

Please try this:

```
$number = 8;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Run FROM users WHERE id='$number'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo 'Result: '.$row['column_goes_here'].'<br><br>';

if($row['column_goes_here'] < 1) {
    echo "Database value is 0 and thus NOT updated today";
} elseif($row['column_goes_here'] == 1) {
    echo "Database value is 1 and thus HAS been updated today";
} else {
    echo "Database value is NOT 1 or 0 and thus something broke";
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. And I didn't think of looking up the Resource Id #5 result (sorry for that, late night coding). Thank you Ravi!

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad I could help.